# Bulk Raster combining in MapInfo?

Tags: raster, mapinfo, batch

I am running mapinfo 15.2 (64bit). I have downloaded multiple Landsat 8 scenes with multispectral data. I can combine the bands of a single scene into a single mrr file using the Raster combine function.

Is there any way to process all scenes at once?

Answer (score 1):

You can automate this task using the Raster SDK that also comes with MapInfo Pro Advanced.

Have a look in the folder Raster\Documentation\API in the MapInfo Pro installation folder. Here you will find the help system for the Raster SDK and also a number of samples.

I wrote a very basic article some time back for The MapInfo Pro Journal on [how to get started with the MapInfo Raster SDK](http://web.pb.com/mapinfopro-oct-2016/Developer-Dojo-MapInfo-Pro-Raster-API).